# iOS - Cancel constraints animation

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I'm animating constraints the usual way:

```
centerXsettingsBtnConstraint.constant = aValue;

[UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                 animations:^{

                      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

               } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      isAnimating = NO;}];
```

When I'm rotating the device I want to cancel this animation and update constraint with new values.

I tried to call

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

but the animation still goes on till the rotation of the device is over. Only then I can update with new constraints, but during the rotation it's all a mess on the screen.

Is there a way to cancel constraints animation?

Answer (score 1):

You must call the remove.. method on each subview:

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

I'll use Swift:

```
for eachView in self.view.subviews {
    eachView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Comment: You have an alternate option: This may answer the question, but would be more helpful with [evidence](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/206345) to support it, for example a short program, or a link to documentation or specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove animation on the specified view whose constraint or property is being changed in that particular animation.

Call *removeAllAnimations()* on the view on whom *centerXsettingsBtnConstraint* is applied.

You **do not** need to call removeAllAnimations() on each subview.

If you are not able to find the particular view, try to print *someView.layer.animationKeys()*, you will find the view on which animation is applied.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:
This will work to stop the animation of the constraint

```
yourComponent.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "position")
```